# append string before strdup C

Tags: c, string

I have this code:

```
if(S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)){
  (*ls)[count++] = strdup(ep->d_name);
  ep = readdir(dp);
} else{
  (*ls)[count++] = strdup(ep->d_name);
  ep = readdir(dp);
}
```

How can i append the string "DIR" to obtain something like:

```
 if(S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)){
      (*ls)[count++] = "DIR "strdup(ep->d_name);
      ep = readdir(dp);
```

So when i'll print it i have this:
file1
file2
DIR: file3
ecc

where `ls` is `char ***ls`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving this: you could use [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/), or if you need to make multiple modifications you could use [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

```
size_t len = strlen(ep->d_name);
// You need five characters for "DIR: ", and one more for the terminating zero:
(*ls)[count] = malloc(len+6);
strcpy((*ls)[count], "DIR: ");      // Copy the prefix
strcat((*ls)[count++], ep->d_name); // Append the name
```

Comment: `sprintf` is very unsafe. Prefer `snprintf`.

Comment: 1) why i need 5 chars? 2) it is correct to do `free((*ls)[count]);` ?

Comment: @polslinux That's the length of `DIR: ` - three letters, a colon, and a space.

Comment: Any solution with `strcpy` and `strcat` encourages dangerous programming practices. Aside from that, you failed to check the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: @R.. That is not universally true: if you are in a single-threaded environment, and you do your `strlen`s ahead of `strcpy`'s/`strcat`s, you will be OK. As for not checking the return value of `malloc`, I see little point in adding it to a tiny snippet that borders on pseudocode: everyone knows to check their `malloc` results anyway, so I don't think that it is necessary to re-emphasize the point in an answer to a question that is not directly related to `malloc`.

Comment: I didn't -1 your answer or anything, and I don't claim your specific code is dangerous aside from the failure to check that `malloc` succeeded. However, use of `strcpy` and `strcat` where `snprintf` (or a higher-level function built on it, ala `asprintf`) is called for is a programming style that leads both to exploitable mistakes (either careless/typo/off-by-one types, or complete ignorance) and often quadratic-time performance (due to repeated `strlen`-like operations).

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been pointed out yet: the code as posted overruns the allocated buffer by one char.  Try `(*ls)[count] = malloc(strlen("DIR: ") + strlen(ep->d_name) + 1);` instead.  But I think I'd prefer s function that manages those details such as in the `asprintf()` answer or the one I posted instead of handcrafting the solution each time you need it (that's how bugs are born).

Comment: @MichaelBurr You're right, it should be `len+6`, not `len+5`. This is now fixed.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: but the main point remains - this kind of code is error prone.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is using the (nonstandard) function `asprintf`

```
if(asprintf(&(*ls)[count++], "DIR %s", ep->d_name) == -1) /* error */;
```

It allocates the the pointer in `(*ls)[count++]` the same way as `malloc` (and your `strdup`).

Comment: where is it included?? I'm on linux and i cannot find it!

Comment: `asprintf` is a GNU-specific function with a really clunky interface, but in principle this is the right way to do it. You can always write your own version of `asprintf` in terms of `snprintf` anyway.

Comment: @R..: Why clunky? It seems fine to me, as easy to use as it gets. The committee seems to have endorsed it in [TR 24731-2](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1337.pdf).

Comment: I understand that the intent is to be analogous to `printf` and return the character count, but sometimes it's really annoying to have to get the result of an allocation function by passing a double-pointer. For instance if you're going to store the result in a `void *`, you have to make an extra `char *` temp whose address you'll pass to `asprintf`, then convert it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `asprintf` which allocates a string and `printf`s to it. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

asprintf(&((*ls)[count++]) "DIR%s", ed->d_name);
```

I'm guessing that `ls` is a pointer to an array of `char *`. Remember to free the strings later!

Comment: Yep, you can read `char ***ls` as 'pointer to an array of char*`.

Comment: but where's asprintf inclued?? I cannot find it!

Comment: It's in `stdio.h`, I have added to my answer.

Comment: i got: `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘asprintf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: Did you include the stdio.h header? Your compiler should link it automatically as it's pretty standard.

Comment: @polslinux: `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including `<stdio.h>`, as described in `asprintf(3)`. Note that `asprintf`, while extremely useful, is non-standard.

Comment: @larsmans: Yes but it's easy enough to write your own. Preferably with a saner interface (like returning a string pointer rather than taking `char **`)...

Comment: That's true. It's really just `snprintf`, `malloc`, `snprintf`.

Comment: @larsmans: And you can cheat by passing a small automatic buffer to `snprintf` the first time and just `strdup`'ing it if the result fit. This typically gives you double performance versus calling `snprintf` twice. Making the small initial buffer with `malloc` also works and is better in the best-case, but costs more if you end up having to free it (and lots of people make the mistake of using `realloc` rather than `free`/`malloc` here, increasing the cost even more).

Comment: @R..: last time I reimplemented `asprintf` for BSD systems, `realloc` is exactly what I used. What's the problem with it?

Comment: `realloc` copies the data you're about to overwrite with a second call to `snprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Some utility functions that will concatenate an arbitrary number of strings into a dynamically allocated buffer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

/*
  vstrconcat() - return a newly allocated string that is the concatenation of
                all the string passed in the variable length argument list.

        The argument list *must* be terminated with a NULL pointer.

        All other arguments must be char* to ASCIIZ strings.

        Thre return value is a pointer to a dynamically allocated
        buffer that contains a null terminated string with 
        all the argument strings concatenated.

        The returned pointer must be freed with the standard free()
        function.

 */

char* vstrconcat( char const* s1, ...)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    char const* src = NULL;
    char* result = NULL;
    char* curpos = NULL;

    va_list argp;

    if (!s1) {
        return NULL;            // maybe should return strdup("")?
    }

    // determine the buffer size needed

    src = s1;
    va_start(argp, s1);

    while (src) {
        len += strlen(src);     //TODO: protect against overflow

        src = va_arg(argp, char const*);
    }

    va_end(argp);

    result = malloc(len + 1);
    if (!result) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // copy the data

    src = s1;
    va_start(argp, s1);
    curpos = result;

    while (src) {
        size_t tmp = strlen(src);

        memcpy(curpos, src, tmp);
        curpos += tmp;

        src = va_arg(argp, char const*);
    }
    va_end(argp);

    result[len] = '\0';

    return result;
}

/*
    strconcat() - simple wrapper for the common case of concatenating exactly 
                  two strings into a dynamically allocated buffer

 */
char* strconcat( char const* s1, char const* s2)
{
    return vstrconcat( s1, s2, NULL);
}
```

You could call it like so in your example:

```
(*ls)[count++] = strconcat( "DIR ", ep->d_name);
```